# Product of polynomials with restrictions for values at three points and all coefficients (but the absolute one) non-positive

Tags: interpolation

this question is closely related to my other question from yesterday :
[Interpolation of three positive values at 0, 1 and 2 by a polynomial with non-negative coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775730/interpolation-of-three-positive-values-at-0-1-and-2-by-a-polynomial-with-non-ne).

Let $ g $ be a univariate polynomial with real coefficients (actually rational coefficients, but I don't think this will matter) and $ g(0) = 1 $. Is there always another real polynomial $ h $ such that the product $ g h $ satisfies $ (gh)(0) = 1 $ (which, of course implies $ h(0) = 1 $ ) and all coefficients but the absolute one in $ gh $ are non-positive and $ -1 \lt (gh)(1) - 1 \lt 1 $ and $ -2^{r+s} \lt (gh)(2) - 1 \lt 2^{r+s} $ where $ r $ and $ s $ are the degrees of $ g $ and $ h $ ?

Thank you for thinking about it.

Comment: What if $g(1)=0$? Or if $y_1>g(1)>0$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Hmm ... you are right. But this is not what I had in mind ... I reformulated the question. I am sorry, for the confusion.